# Como saber desde una página externa (A) si hay una sesion inciada de otra página (B) en el browser

Tags: laravel, sesiones

tengo un problema con una comunicación entre dominios, yo necesito saber desde la página (A) en js que esta en un dominio (a.dev) si hay una sesión iniciada de la página (B) en laravel que esta en otro dominio  (b.dev) es decir dos servidores diferentes.

Comment: Si entiendo bien, ¿la idea es por medio de JavaScript determinar si hay una sesión de Laravel de X sitio en el mismo navegador?

Comment: Si exacto, eso es lo que quiero.

Comment: @shaz lo has hecho alguna vez? he intentado varias cosas pero no lo he conseguido, cualquier ayuda que me puedas dar sería genial.